# VB.NETのプログラムでのExcelファイル操作について

Tags: excel, vb.net

PC上でVB.NETのプログラムを実行し、Excelファイルの取り込みを行っています。
11月半ばまでは約40分程度で完了するプログラムが、3時間程度かかるようになりました。
なお、取込対象のExcelファイルは様々なバージョンのOffice(2013、2016、2019)で編集したものとなります。

ログを確認したところ、Excelファイルのオープンに3～10秒かかっており、
それが原因で処理時間がかかっているようです。
VB.NETのプログラムを実行しているPCのイベントログを確認したところ、
バージョン「16.0.5083.1000」のExcel.exeで異常が発生していました。

おそらくですが、Excel.exeで異常が発生したため、
Excelファイルのオープンで時間がかかっているのだと考えられます。
Excel.exeで異常が発生している原因ですが、どのようなことが考えられますでしょうか。

実行マシンの環境は以下となっています。
OS　　 :Windows 10(64Bit)
Office：Office2016

Comment: どのような異常が発生しているのですか？　また、それをどのようにして確認したのですか？　「異常が発生した」だけから原因を考えるのは無理です。　もっと詳しい状況や情報を質問に追加してください。

Answer (score 0):

Excel の問題なら [Microsoft コミュニティ](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/)に質問した方が速いと思いますよ。